# old issue with ggplot & geom_boxplot & geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

my name is Giacomo and I'm just a R beginner.
I'm trying to produce a boxplot graphic overlayied by two trendlines, one for each classes I plotted.

Googling I found many examples, like this 
[ggplot - Add regression line on a boxplot with binned (non-continuous) x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296789/ggplot-add-regression-line-on-a-boxplot-with-binned-non-continuous-x-axis/27696167#27696167)
but it doesn't work for me.

At the end I tryied two different ways, the first is:

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(y=S1_VH)) +  
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=as.factor(DOY), fill = X2cycles)) +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, aes(x=as.integer(DOY), color=X2cycles)) +    
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                           
                     name="Rice Cycles")+                                                            
  scale_color_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                          
                    name="Rice Cycles")+                                                             
  labs(x = "DOY", y = "VH")+                                                                         
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),                                                             
        axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"),                                                
        legend.text=element_text(size=20),                                                           
        legend.title=element_text(size=25))+                                                         
  ylim(-24,-14)
```

pros: both the trendlines are correctly shown, 
cons: boxplot and trendlines are not overlayied

The second way is

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=factor(DOY), y=S1_VH, fill = X2cycles))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, aes(group=1, color=X2cycles)) +    
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                           
                     name="Rice Cycles")+                                                            
  scale_color_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                          
                    name="Rice Cycles")+                                                             
  labs(x = "DOY", y = "VH")+                                                                         
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),                                                             
        axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"),                                                
        legend.text=element_text(size=20),                                                           
        legend.title=element_text(size=25))+                                                         
  ylim(-24,-14)
```

pros: boxplot and one trendline are correctly overlayied,
cons: only one trendline is plotted

Can you help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: 1. Please post a _minimal, self-contained_ example. 2. Please read the manual (`?geom_boxplot`). "You can also use boxplots with continuous x, as long as you supply a grouping variable."

Comment: @Henrik: thank you very much. I read the manual carefully but I'm a beginner and I canno't solve my problem (by now). fileIn is the name of my dataframe. How can I attach this file or how can I provide you this file? THank you again

Comment: I solved the problem. It was easy. This is the solution:  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, aes(group=X2cycles, color=X2cycles)) +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Thank you anyway.

```
    plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=factor(DOY), y=S1_VH, fill = X2cycles))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, aes(group=X2cycles, color=X2cycles)) +    
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                           
                     name="Rice Cycles")+                                                            
  scale_color_manual(values=c("ShortCycle"= "brown", "LongCycle" = "grey"),                          
                    name="Rice Cycles")+                                                             
  labs(x = "DOY", y = "VH")+                                                                         
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=20),                                                             
        axis.title=element_text(size=20,face="bold"),                                                
        legend.text=element_text(size=20),                                                           
        legend.title=element_text(size=25))+                                                         
  ylim(-24,-14)
```

Comment: As already pointed out in [the post you refer to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296789/ggplot-add-regression-line-on-a-boxplot-with-binned-non-continuous-x-axis) "_it is a stunningly bad idea_" and "_can be misleading_" to add a smoother when the x-axis is discrete. I believe it would be better to use boxplots with continuous x using the method described in `?geom_boxplot`

Comment: Thanks you for your feedback. Good luck with your plotting!

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my delay. I changed my script in order to use continuous X in my plot.

```
plotSerie <- ggplot(fileIn, aes(x=DOY, y=S1_VH, fill = pass, group=DOY))+
  geom_boxplot() +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=TRUE, aes(group=pass, color=pass)) +
```

Thank you very much