# Boxplot with a regression line using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a boxplot with a regression on it, however the graphs don't get overlapped, the regression remains too far to the right, getting very strange.

My data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sk68TLZsd9KV46LTIQ9R_f6bNEjwp2mE/view?usp=sharing

My plot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSNcQ.jpg

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Dados_geom_smooth[!is.na(Dados_geom_smooth$Day),]) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=factor(Day), y = absolute_CD45posi, fill = Grupos_gravidade),
               position=position_dodge(.7),width=.8)+
  geom_smooth(aes(x=as.integer(Day),
                  y=absolute_CD45posi, color=Grupos_gravidade,
                  fill=Grupos_gravidade),method=loess) + 
  facet_wrap(~ Grupos_gravidade) + 
  theme_bw()

dev.copy(tiff,"absolute_CD45posi.tiff",width=4, height=3, units="in",res=300)
dev.off()
```

**PROBLEM SOLUTION**

```
geom_smooth(aes(x=as.numeric(as.factor(Day)),
                  y=absolute_CD45posi, color=Grupos_gravidade,
                  fill=Grupos_gravidade),method=loess)  +  
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("2","5", "10"))
```

Reference : [ggplot - Add regression line on a boxplot with binned (non-continuous) x-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296789/ggplot-add-regression-line-on-a-boxplot-with-binned-non-continuous-x-axis)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSNcQ.jpg

Comment: The x axis of a boxplot is a series of factors.  Rescale your regression data so they lie along the range from 1 to the number of boxes in the plot and it should coincide.

Comment: Dear  Dan Slone,
 I am trying with the function:   scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2, 10)) ,  but always returns an error:
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Greetings! For future reference, posting your data in this way isn't best. Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems and one great way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg